# Match attribute value of XML string in JS

Tags: javascript, xml, regex, xml-parsing

I've researched stackoverflow and find similar results but it is not really what I wanted.

Given an xml string: `"<a b=\"c\"></a>"` in javascript context, **I want to create a regex that will capture the attribute value including the quotation marks**.

NOTE: this is similar if you're using single quotation marks.

Currently I have a regular expression tailored to the XML specification:

```
[_A-Za-z][\w\.\-]*(?:=\"[^\"]*\")?

[_A-Za-z][\w\.\-]*     //This will match the attribute name.
(?:=\"[^\"]*\")?       //This will match the attribute value.


\"[^\"]*\"             //This part concerns me.
```

My question now is, what if the xml string looks like this:

```
<shout statement="Hi! \"Richeve\"."></shout>
```

I know this is a dumb question to ask but I just want to capture rare cases that this scenario might happen (I know the coder can use single quotes on this scenario) but there are cases that we don't know the current value of the attribute given that the attribute value changes dynamically at runtime.

So to make this clearer, the result of that using the correct regex should be:

```
"Hi! \"Richeve\"."
```

I hope my question is clear. Thanks for all the help!

*PS: Note that the language context is Javascript and I know it is tempting to use lookbehinds but currently lookbehinds are not supported.*

*PS: I know it is really hard to parse XML but I have an elegant solution to this :) so I just need this small problem to be solved. So this problem only main focus is capturing quotation marked string tokens containing quotation marks inside the string token.*

Comment: Read: http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2009/11/parsing-html-the-cthulhu-way.html

Comment: This is funny but for every problem there's always a solution. Don't give up :) I think I will have to edit the question to focus only on the quotation marks. Since this is only the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The standard pattern for content with matching delimiters and embedded escaped delimiters goes like this:

```
"[^"\\]*(?:\\.[^"\\]*)*"
```

Ignoring the obvious first and last characters in the pattern, here's how the rest of the pattern works:

`[^"\\]*`: Consume all characters until a delimiter OR backslash (matching `Hi!` in your example)

`(?:\\.[^"\\]*)*` Try to consume a single escaped character `\\.` followed by a series of non delimiter/backslash characters, repeatedly (matching `\"Richeve` first and then `\".` next in your example)

That's it.

You can try to use a more generic delimiter approach using `(['"])` and back references, or you can just allow for an alternate pattern with single quotes like so:

```
("[^"\\]*(?:\\.[^"\\]*)*"|'[^'\\]*(?:\\.[^'\\]*)*')
```

Here's another description of this technique that might also help (see the section called Strings): http://www.regular-expressions.info/examplesprogrammer.html

Answer (score 0):

## Description

I'm pretty really sure embedding double quotes inside a double quoted attribute value is not legal. You could use the unicode equivalent of a double quote `\x22` inside the value.

**However** to answer the question, this expression will:

- allow escaped quotes inside attribute values
- capture the attribute `statement` 's  value
- allow attributes to appear in any order inside the tag
- will avoid many of the edge cases which will trip up pattern matching inside html text
- doesn't use lookbehinds

`<shout\b(?=\s)(?=(?:[^>=]|='(?:[^']|\\')*'|="(?:[^"]|\\")*"|=[^'"][^\s>]*)*?\sstatement=(['"])((?:\\['"]|.)*?)\1(?:\s|\/>|>))(?:[^>=]|='(?:[^']|\\')*'|="(?:[^"]|\\")*"|=[^'"][^\s>]*)*>.*?<\/shout>`

[image]

## Example

- [Pretty Rubular](http://www.rubular.com/r/c9CGLjwY4A)
- [Ugly RegexPlanet set to Javascript](http://www.rubular.com/r/c9CGLjwY4A)

**Sample Text**

Note the difficult edge case in the first attribute :)

```
<shout onmouseover=' statement="He said \"I am Inside the onMouseOver\" " ; if ( 6 > a ) { funRotate(statement) } ; ' statement="Hi! \"Richeve\"." title="sometitle">SomeString</shout>
```

**Matches**

Group 0 gets the entire tag from open to close
Group 1 gets the quote surrounding the statement attribute value, this is used to match the closing quote correctly
Group 2 gets the statement attribute value which may include escaped quotes like `\"` but not including the surrounding quotes

```
[0][0] = <shout onmouseover=' statement="He said \"I am Inside the onMouseOver\" " ; if ( 6 > a ) { funRotate(statement) } ; ' statement="Hi! \"Richeve\"." title="sometitle">SomeString</shout>
[0][1] = "
[0][2] = Hi! \"Richeve\".
```